# "show" segue inside UITabBarController & UINavigationController does not push

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios10, xcode8

I have the following setup:

```
UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> ViewController1
```

I noticed that when I create a segue from `ViewController1` to another `ViewController2` and use Kind "Show (e.g. Push)", it will actually not push but display ViewController2 modally. If I change the Kind of the segue to deprecated type of "Push", it will push `ViewController2` correctly.

**Why is this happening and is there any way to avoid using the deprecated push segue to get my intended behaviour?**